# Problem with PyInstaller ''INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg''

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using the command ''pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py'' to convert my python file into .exe, When I try to convert my py file to .exe the following message appears on cmd,  :

```
88006 INFO: checking PKG
88008 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
88009 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
```